# Calculate the lenght of list items with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, django, html-lists

I have setup a Javascript function that generate random numbers for every of my search results which are list items and I want to calculate the lenght of the list without knowing in advance the number of search results that will be displayed since every queries are different.

Is there any ways to do that?

Currently, I add a number to `itemLength` manually within this Javascript function because I know the number of results for a particular query:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var orderedList = document.getElementById("my_list");
  var itemLength = 8; //REPLACE THIS WITH THE LENGTH OF THE ITEM LIST

  function getRandomInt(min, max) {
      min = Math.ceil(min);
      max = Math.floor(max);
      return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
  }

  // get a default 100 into the array
  var arrayOfNumbers = [100],
      listItem = document.getElementById("list_item");

  // get itemLength random numbers
  for (let i = 0; i < itemLength; i++) {
    arrayOfNumbers.push(getRandomInt(30, 98))
  }

  // sort the array of random numbers
  arrayOfNumbers.sort(function(a, b) {
    return b - a
  })

  // now do the lopping and creating elements
  for (let i = 0; i < arrayOfNumbers.length; i++) {
    let randomIntContainer = document.createElement('div');
    randomIntContainer.textContent = arrayOfNumbers[i] + "%";
    randomIntContainer.setAttribute('class', 'number');
    listItem = document.getElementById("list_item");
    listItem.appendChild(randomIntContainer);
    orderedList.appendChild(listItem);
  }

</script>
```

But knowing that every queries won't always give 8 results back and that I have to call the results from the backend in the html like this:

```
<div>
   {% if  page_obj.object_list %}
       <ol class="row top20" id="my_list">

          {% for result in page_obj.object_list %}

          <li id="list_item">
              <div class="showcase col-sm-6 col-md-4">
               <a href="{{ result.object.get_absolute_url }}">
                      <h3>{{result.object.title}}</h3>
                      <h5>{{ result.object.destination }}</h5>
                      <img src="{{ result.object.image }}" class="img-responsive">
               </a>
               </div>
          </li>

           {% endfor %}

       </ol>
</div>
    {% endif %}
```

How can I automaticaly calculate the `itemLength`?

Comment: Well, where does the number of items come from?

Comment: The actual number is not coming from anywhere. There is search results and they come from a postgresql and an Elasticsearch Index. I use Django as a backend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is

```
orderedList.children.length
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, should I do this then? `var itemLength = orderedList.children.length;`

Comment: I think that is correct. Does it work?


If you happen to not understand the code read these two beginner friendly articles


[JavaScript HTML DOM Navigation](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_navigation.asp)


[HTML DOM children Property](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_children.asp)

Comment: It works, thanks so much! Since I have a line that give a default value of 100 by default to the first item I added this line: `var itemLength = orderedList.children.length - 1;`.

Comment: I don't want to make things to hard for you but would you mind taking a look at my other question which is related to the same code? Here's the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56095052/changing-place-of-a-javascript-generated-div